# Insert dataFrame into another dataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need to insert a `dataframe` into another `dataframe` column,
how do I need to do it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('X_F', 'Y_F', 'Z_F', 'Label'))
    df['X_F'] = X[uid]
    df['Y_F'] = Y[uid]
    df['Z_F'] = Z[uid]
```

It shows me

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can merge two or more data frames using [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: i dont need to merge, i need to add it into the column...

Comment: Do you mean nested dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not perfectly sure what are you trying to achieve, but you can use `MultiIndex` if you want to store dataframes inside dataframe.

Please see the example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3],
                    'B': list('abc'),
                    'C': [3.3,2.7,9.1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4,5,6],
                    'B': list('def'),
                    'C': [1.7,0.3,2.8]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7,8,9],
                    'B': list('ghi'),
                    'C': [0.3,0.4,0.5]})

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
names = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

result = {}

for df, name in zip(dfs, names):
    data = df.to_dict()
    for key, value in data.items():
        result[(name, key)] = value

dff = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Now `dff` is the dataframe with `MultiIndex` that looks like this:

```
   X          Y          Z        
   A  B    C  A  B    C  A  B    C
0  1  a  3.3  4  d  1.7  7  g  0.3
1  2  b  2.7  5  e  0.3  8  h  0.4
2  3  c  9.1  6  f  2.8  9  i  0.5
```

And if you want to take dataframe `Y` from it you can use:

```
dff['Y']
#   A  B    C
#0  4  d  1.7
#1  5  e  0.3
#2  6  f  2.8
```

Hope this helps.